# Laravel | Display images order by order

Tags: eloquent

i have function show:

```
 public function show(ArtbookRepository $artRepository, $id) {
    $artbook = Artbook::where('id', $id)->with(['videos', 'photos', 'covers', 'documents'])->first();
        return view('pages.staff.artbooks.show', [
            "artbook" => $artbook,
        ]);
    }
```

Artbooks are in relationship with photos: Artbook 1:N Photos
but my photos table have column "order" and how can I modify this eloquent query to get ordered photos?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$artbook = Artbook::where('id', $id)->with(['videos', 'photos'=>function($q) {
            $q->orderBy('order', 'asc');
        }, 'covers', 'documents'])->first();
```

Ok works :)